# Can't find ULS Log file

Tags: logging, uls, logs

I'm trying to find ULS logs file, so I went and configured the **diagnostic logging** in the

> central administration > Monitoring.

I've selected **all the categories**,

> Set minimum level of trace
>
> Event log at verbose
>
> Set the file directory to : C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS.

But when I go into this file I can't see any log.What is the reason behind it and how I can I see my logs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a permission problem!

Have you had *any* log files on that machine?

I have seen before in installations, that the web application pool users dont get added to the Performance Log Users

```
Computer > Manage > Configuration > Groups > Performance Log Users
```

You should also check if they are members of Performance Monitor Users group as well

Comment: Just did that, Someone told me to wait 24hours, so i'm gonna wait until tomorrow :) but it might be this :)

Comment: Did that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft ULS Viewer and try to get Real time ULS log and see if you can save it or where it has been saved.

[Microsoft ULS Log Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer/)

Comment: Hi, I've tried this, and nothing is updating in the program neither !